# How to authorize a Python Google API client service given an OAuth2 access_token?

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, python-social-auth, oauth2client

I have implemented the [python-social-auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth) library for Google OAuth2 in my Django project, and am successfully able to log users in with it. The library stores the `access_token` received in the response for Google's OAuth2 flow.

My question is: use of the [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) seems to rely on creating and authorizing a `credentials` object, then using it to build an API `service` like so:

```
...
# send user to Google consent URL, get auth_code in response

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

from apiclient.discovery import build
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)

# use service for API calls...
```

Since I'm starting with an `access_token` provided by python-social-auth, how do I create & authorize the API client `service` for future API calls?

**Edit**: to clarify, the code above is from the examples provided by Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given you already have the OAuth2 access token you can use the [`AccessTokenCredentials`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#AccessTokenCredentials) class.

> The oauth2client.client.AccessTokenCredentials class is used when you have already obtained an access token by some other means. You can create this object directly without using a Flow object.

Example:

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenCredentials

credentials = AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, user_agent)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

Comment: @danielx, how can i get `access_token`?

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey there are numerous ways to get an `access_token`, check out this guide: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_overview

Answer (score 2):

If you have an already refreshed latest access token which is not expired, then you can get `service` variable as:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials


creds = Credentials("<ACCESS_TOKEN>")
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

# Call the Gmail API
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check examples provided by Google Guide API, for example: sending email via gmail application, https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: Unfortunately all of that code (that I've found) assumes that you have `service: Authorized Gmail API service instance` - I haven't figured out how to authorize a `service` given an `access_token`.